# Python function is not working "Help"

Tags: python

**this first code im going to show you works**

```
def spam():
    """Prints the word eggs!"""

    egg = "Eggs!"

    print (egg)



spam()
```

**But this one does not work i don't under stand**

```
def spam():
    """Prints the word eggs!"""

    print "Eggs!"



spam()
```

**Turns out i was missing the brackets in the print "Eggs!" should have been print ("Eggs!")**

Comment: You can see how your code looks like while posting. Please take a look at it while posting and format your code appropriately. I have fixed it for you, but do make sure next time you format it properly.

Comment: are you using python 3? because you need brackets around your `print` parameters

Comment: also, your docstring lies, it prints `Eggs!` not `eggs!`

Comment: thanks i am new and im just exploring it is my first post so "yeah"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using python 3, since it requires parentheses with a print statement.
Try to do:

```
print("Eggs!")
```

Instead of:

```
print "Eggs!"
```

Notice how your first function has parenthesis:

```
print(egg)
```

That's why it works.